# Multi-level models and residuals

Tags: regression, multilevel-analysis, hierarchical-bayesian

As one increases the number of levels in a multi-level model, should one expect the output model **variance** to go down?

That is, as we increase levels in our model:

- Full pooling:
  $y_i \sim  \text{N}\left(\beta x_i, \sigma^2_y\right)$
- Two-level pooling:
  $y_i \sim  \text{N}\left(\alpha_{j[i]} + \beta x_i, \sigma^2_y\right)$
- etc..

Is it fair to assume that $\sigma^2_y$ would go **down**?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I was aware, as the variance of y is calculated independently of the model, it shouldn't change.  The model will look at how that variance is explained by the different model levels, though - look at the idea of the Variance Partition model and the Variance Partition Coefficient (VPC) for information on that.  Joop Hox's book has some very good explanations (and some chapters are previewed on his website: http://joophox.net/ ).  Full ref: Hox, J. J. (2010). Multilevel analysis: techniques and applications (2. ed). New York: Routledge, Taylor & Francis.  3rd ed is a bit updated, but second or first does well enough.